# Telegram Bot Inline Buttons Not Responding

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm facing an issue with my Python Telegram bot. I've implemented inline buttons for users to approve or reject a request. However, the bot doesn't seem to respond when I click on these buttons.

I'm using the Telegram Bot API in Python.
I have implemented inline buttons with callback data.
The buttons are displayed correctly, but when I click on them, nothing happens.
I suspect that there might be an issue with my callback handling or how I'm extracting data from the message. Here's a simplified version of my code for handling inline buttons:

```
def process_id_input(message, user_id, product_info, product_price):
    user_folder_path = os.path.join("users_data", str(user_id))
    user_file_path = os.path.join(user_folder_path, "user_data.json")
    with open(user_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as user_file:
        user_data = json.load(user_file)

    target_user_id = message.text
    invoice_id = generate_invoice_id()

    server_time = datetime.now()

    adjusted_time = server_time + timedelta(hours=3)

    purchase_record = {
        "product_name": product_info["name"],
        "price": product_price,
        "invoice_id": invoice_id,
        "purchase_time": adjusted_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        "target_user_id": target_user_id,
        "order_status": "قيد التنفيذ"
    }

    user_folder_path = os.path.join("users_data", str(user_id))
    purchases_file_path = os.path.join(user_folder_path, "purchases.json")
    if os.path.exists(purchases_file_path):
        with open(purchases_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as purchases_file:
            user_purchases = json.load(purchases_file)
    else:
        user_purchases = []

    user_purchases.append(purchase_record)

    with open(purchases_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as purchases_file:
        json.dump(user_purchases, purchases_file)

    for admin_chat_id in admins:
        admin_message = ("استخدم الأمر /ss لتعيين حالة الطلب\n"
                         " طلب جديد!\n\n"
                         f"المستخدم: {user_data['name']}\n"
                         f"المنتج: {product_info['name']}\n"
                         f"السعر: {product_price} SYP\n"
                         f"رقم الفاتورة: `{invoice_id}`\n"
                         f"الايدي المراد التحويل اليه: `{target_user_id}`\n"
                         "حالة الطلب: قيد التنفيذ")

        approve_button = InlineKeyboardButton("موافق", callback_data=f"approve_{invoice_id}")
        reject_button = InlineKeyboardButton("رفض", callback_data=f"reject_{invoice_id}")

        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[approve_button, reject_button]])

        try:
            bot.send_message(admin_chat_id, admin_message, parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=keyboard)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to send admin message: {e}")

    thank_message = f"شكرًا لك على شراء {product_info['name']}!\n\nرقم الفاتورة: `{invoice_id}`\n\nيتم الآن معالجة طلبك من قبل الإدارة."

    try:
        bot.send_message(user_id, thank_message, parse_mode='Markdown')
        show_main_menu(user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send thank you message to the user: {e}")
      
def handle_inline_buttons(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    data = query.data
    user_id = query.from_user.id

    try:
        invoice_id = query.message.text.split("رقم الفاتورة: `")[1].split("`")[0]

        if data.startswith("approve_"):
            update_purchase_status(user_id, invoice_id, "مكتملة")
        elif data.startswith("reject_"):
            update_purchase_status(user_id, invoice_id, "مرفوضة")

        query.answer(text="تم تحديث حالة الطلب بنجاح.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while handling inline buttons: {e}")

def update_purchase_status(user_id, invoice_id, status):
    user_folder_path = os.path.join("users_data", str(user_id))
    purchases_file_path = os.path.join(user_folder_path, "purchases.json")

    if os.path.exists(purchases_file_path):
        with open(purchases_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as purchases_file:
            user_purchases = json.load(purchases_file)

        for purchase in user_purchases:
            if purchase["invoice_id"] == invoice_id:
                purchase["order_status"] = status

        with open(purchases_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as purchases_file:
            json.dump(user_purchases, purchases_file)
```

Comment: You didn't show how you defined your handlers. Please show an [MWE](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/MWE).

Comment: this a full code

Comment: If you're neither defining handlers nor an `telegram.ext.Application` objects, but only handler callbacks, then it's no wonder that no updates are being handled ;)

Comment: how i can do that ?

Comment: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot